# LevelDB key,value from csv

Tags: ip-geolocation, leveldb

I've huge csv file database of ~5M rows having below fields

```
start_ip,end_ip,country,city,lat,long
```

I am storing these in LevelDB using start_ip as the key and rest as the value.

How can I retrieve records for keys where

```
( ip_key > start_ip and ip_key < end_ip )
```

Any alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your keys are the hash values of the IP and the hashes are  64-bit `unsigned' integers, but if that's not the case then just modify the code below to account for the proper keys.

```
void MyClass::ReadRecordRange(const uint64 startRange, const uint64 endRange)
{
    // Get the start slice and the end slice
    leveldb::Slice startSlice(static_cast<const char*>(static_cast<const void*>(&startRange)), sizeof(startRange));
    leveldb::Slice endSlice(static_cast<const char*>(static_cast<const void*>(&endRange)), sizeof(endRange));

    // Get a database iterator
    shared_ptr<leveldb::Iterator> dbIter(_database->NewIterator(leveldb::ReadOptions()));

    // Possible optimization suggested by Google engineers 
    // for critical loops. Reduces memory thrash.
    for(dbIter->Seek(startSlice); dbIter->Valid() && _options.comparator->Compare(dbIter->key(), endSlice)<=0); dbIter->Next())
    {
        // get the key
        dbIter->key().data();

        // get the value
        dbIter->value().data();

        // TODO do whatever you need to do with the key/value you read
    }
}
```

Note that `_options` are the same `leveldb::Options` with which you opened the database instance. You want to use the comparator specified in the options so that the order in which you read the records is the same as the order in the database.

If you're not using boost or tr1, then you can either use something else similar to the `shared_ptr` or just delete the `leveldb::Iterator` by yourself. If you don't delete the iterator, then you'll leak memory and get asserts in debug mode.

Comment: am using leveldb-jni bindings from fusesource(https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni). Though that's not the issue for logic. Am using  ipv4/ipv6 bytes in keys and need to find out input query belongs to some range.

Comment: Ah, ok... well, I'm only familiar with the C++ library, so I'm not sure how to do it in Java, but I looked at the source code just now and it seems that you just have to get the `DBIterator` by calling the DB's `iterator(...)` method. From there on, I assume you can use the same logic as above. If you just want to figure out if the key belongs to some range, then use the `NativeComparator` to test if the key is between the given range.

Comment: thanks. Its the other way though. I want to find a range where input belongs; and am storing only start of range as key. there are no overlapping ranges hence this should be fine.

Comment: OK, so that answers your question? As I see it, your database has the keys [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and you call `ReadRecordRange(4, 7)` it will read the keys [4, 5, 6, 7]. That's the behavior you want, correct?

Comment: No, lets say my keys are [1,3,5,7,9] so for key 4 I need to get a record with key==3. key 1 is for all the items in range 1-2,same for key 7 which maps to all items in range 7-8.  Since all my records are already sorted and no overlapping ranges it worked as below. I seek with dbiterator and then check for prev record. It worked!

Comment: @Ketan, gald it works :)... let me know if my answer pointed you in the right direction.